# Customizing virtual home button's app launcher

Tags: customization, home-button, nova-launcher

I currently acquired a Motorola G and I'm wishing to add another application to the pop menu that appears when press-holding the home button besides the one that calls the search engine. I'm currently using Nova Launcher but I couldn't find any information in system configurations or Nova configurations.

Comment: Nova launcher/Nova launcher Prime doesn't offer this feature. Also, to my knowledge, there is no such launcher which can customize the behaviour of soft keys. Have only seen this thing in custom ROMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SwipeUp Utility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianCampos.swipeuputility) to change the behaviour of the search action (swiping the home button) to launch a different app or shortcut.

I've contributed to this app (I helped the author fix a bug) but I've no financial interest in it.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Must give it a whirl.

Comment: Thank mate, this helped me a lot, I wanted something else to pop-up instead of the search engine.